# Winsock - Does WSAConnect() delegate to connect()?

Tags: c++, networking, winsock

Does anyone know if the implementation of WSAConnect finally calls the standard connect method?

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly the other way around, since `WSAConnect` supports connect data and QOS settings, and `connect` doesn't.

On the other hand, the only reason you'd care is if you're trying to intercept sockets functions without using the supported methods designed for that purpose.

Comment: I'm writing some kind of monitoring utility and need to count tcp connections. I need to know if hooking to both functions is needed or only to connect is enough. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Adibarda: If you're intercepting it correctly, you won't have that problem.  Write an LSP, don't use hooking.

Answer (score 3):

No. They might call the same internal function, but they certainly **do not** call each other. Try putting a breakpoint on both `WSAConnect` and `connect`. You'll see that only one of them will be triggered, not both if you make either calls.